# how do I install more vpn plugins to ubuntu network?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

The default PPTP is there but how do I get IPSEC in that dropdown?

[image]

Comment: You may need to install more packages. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/569763/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-14-10

Comment: What kind of "ipsec"? Cisco? L2TP? IKEv2?

Comment: L2TP I tried Big Chris's answer rebooted but still only PPTP in list.